# ADO Self-Hosted agents under Linux as a Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a weird issue when executing an ADO release using my self-hosted agents (running in a Ubuntu VM). These agents are configured as a service as well.
When I ran the release, they return this error:

> ***##[error]Unhandled: Failed to find the specified JDK version. Please ensure the specified JDK version is installed on the agent and the environment variable 'JAVA_HOME_11_X64' exists and is set to the location of a corresponding JDK or use the [Java Tool Installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=875287) task to install the desired JDK.***

I've checked the value of Java variable, and it's configured ok.

What is weird in this situation is that if I execute the agent manually, and not as a service, the deployment works correctly...

Any idea about what could be wrong here?

Regards!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwV2e.jpg

Comment: Hi, it should be noted that for any `environment variable` changes(after the agent service is started or is currently running); we need to [update environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#service-update-environment-variables).

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT I'm not tested yet, sorry. I will try to configure as a service following your recomendations and reply over your message.

Answer (score 1):

Under **vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.204.0.tar.gz** you will have

1. config.sh
2. env.sh

by default env.sh does not have entry for JAVA_HOME_11_X64 and this env.sh is used to add all system capabilities. if JAVA_HOME_11_X64 needs to be added as system capabilities make your you edit the .env file and add JAVA_HOME_11_X64. if added after build agent is stared then you need to restart the agent gain to show as capabilities.

I have added the script for

> if [ ! -f ".env" ]; then
> touch .env fi echo "JAVA_HOME_11_X64=${JAVA_HOME_11_X64}" >>.env

before config.sh is executed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `JAVA_HOME_11_X64` system environment variable into VM.

**Then**, you should re-run the `run.cmd` to update the environment to your agent tool.

**After that**, please check Project Settings-->Pipeline-->Agent Pools-->`your agent tool`--> agent--> click more for update agent. And you could also enter [Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#view-agent-details) to check if there is a environment variable called `JAVA_HOME_11_X64`. If not, you could also add its value under **User-defined capabilities**.

**Last**, use a pipeline to run [javatoolinstaller task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) for your self-agent, and then you can use the java11 jdk directly.

**Besides**, check the self agent security permission and you have the right.